# How to find bounding box lat longs of worldwind current view?

Tags: java, worldwind

I'm working with worldwind and I'm trying to find the cordinates upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right of the current worldwind view.

When I say cordinates i'm looking for the +/- 90 degrees latitude and +/- 180 degrees longitude.  Whats the easiest way to do this.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your question, please indicate as much by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindow`, say, `worldWindow`, then you can get its current view like so:

```
View curView = worldWindow.getView();
```

... where `curView` is of the class `gov.nasa.worldwind.View`; see [here](https://nasaworldwind.github.io/WorldWindJava/gov/nasa/worldwind/View.html).  Then, you can get the view's "view port" like so:

```
Rectangle viewPort = curView.getViewport();
```

... where `viewPort` is a `java.awt.Rectangle`.  Next, we need to compute the position from the screen point of each point of that rectangle:

```
Position topLeft = curView.computePositionFromScreenPoint(0, 0);
Position botRight = curView.computePositionFromScreenPoint(viewPort.width, viewPort.height);
```

... where `topLeft`, `botRight` are each of the class `gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position`.  The lower left and upper right should be obvious from the construction given above.

Answer (score 1):

gov.nasa.worldwind.View has a method *computePositionFromScreenPoint*